# File availability in asp.net core project during testing

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm running a number of projects using asp.net core and they're being run in docker containers on Linux.

I want to have certain values available to my code and it's been convenient to create simple '.ini' files which can contain string values which can be easily updated during build and deployment.

I store them in the wwwroot folder and I load them in using ReadAllText

```
var cfg = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"/wwwroot/app.ini").TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
```

This works fine in both Visual Studio and in the containers. 
But when I'm trying to run unit tests the CurrentDirectory is no longer the project directory, but a build folder in the Unit Testing project. wwwroot is no longer available.

So what should I do/ be doing?

- Not use files?
- Place them elsewhere?
- Handle them differently in build?
- Use something other than Directory.GetCurrentDirectory?

Comment: Why dont you use the Configuration Options provided by asp net core? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration. (You could also move the code which reads you ini file into a service and mock this service during tests, but I would really have a look at the built in Configuration Options)

Comment: But aren't the file-based configuration options based on Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() (first example) or uses the StartUp functon which isn't called when running tests? 

The creation of a mockable service, or just a singleton sounds like maybe the way to go.

Comment: I feel like I would have to agree with @Riscie on this. Perhaps see if there's a way to re-write your unite tests such that they use the ConfigurationOptions classes  to read in your configuration files, or to pass in a configuration object (which represents a known configuration) or a range of them (some with "good" configs and some with "bad", depending on your tests).

Comment: Post your unit test code and unit tests configuration - problem is solvable but requiers more info.